# After executing a trigger on insert I receive Error Code 1136

Tags: mysql

my trigger is execute simply,

```
use bd_schema
DELIMITER $$
create trigger triggername1 after insert on user
for each row
begin
insert into user2(sid,sname,marks)values(
new.sid,new.sname,new.marks);
END$$
DELIMITER
```

But I'm getting an error, when I'm inserting a row in the table.

```
INSERT INTO `bd_schema`.`user` (`sid`, `sname`, `marks`) VALUES ('3', 'vam', '92');
```

I receive this error:

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: so  what table are you trying to insert? `user` or `user2`?

Comment: error code:1136 column count doesn't match value count at row1

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are providing not as much data as the table `bd_schema` does contain columns. And now the DB engine does not know in which columns to put your data.

To overcome this you must provide the names of the columns you want to fill. Example:

`insert into bd_schema (column_name1, column_name2) values (1, 3)`

Look up the table definition and see which columns you want to fill.

Comment: i am trying to insert on user2,i tried to insert a row like these

Comment: i insert like these INSERT INTO `bd_schema`.`user` (`sid`, `sname`, `marks`) VALUES ('3', 'vam', '92');